# How can I enable / disable Xcode's Main Thread Checker from the command line?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'd like to be able to enable / disable Xcode's [Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker) from the xcodebuild command line. What switch should I use? I do not want to set this in an .xcconfig file.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: I do not recall finding an answer to this issue other than a .xcconfig.